# Как динамически добавить кастомизированный layout

Tags: android, android-view

Написал вот такой класс и xml. Как добавить его в проект? Надо чтобы выглядело примерно так: `TextView textView = new TextView(context)`. Как я понимаю это называется динамически.

```
public class LayoutImageView extends LinearLayout {
    @BindView(R.id.text)
    TextView textView;

    @BindView(R.id.image)
    ImageView view;


    public LayoutImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    public void setText(Spanned text) {
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    public void setImage(String url) {
        Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(url)
                .into(view);
    }
}
```

**xml**

```
<LayoutImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/image_text_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ddd"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_padding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_padding">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@color/cardview_dark_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="@dimen/post_text_size" />

</LayoutImageView>
```

Comment: Ну точно также как и вы написали с `TextView`: `LayoutImageView view = LayoutImageView(context);`

Comment: Ну да, только если так сделать, то не найдет TextView и ImageView в LayoutImageView ))

Comment: @артемШеломенцев, почему не найдёт? Как вы пробовали искать? В чём у вас конкретно проблема? Разницы между своим виджетом и системный никакой нет.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не найдем по моему мнению из за того что я не правильно написал класс LayoutImageView, так как там не хватает ссылки на xml версию. А ошибка: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'text' with ID 2131558540 for field 'textView' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.

Comment: @артемШеломенцев, да, у вас ваша разметка не загружена. См. мой ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не загрузили вашу разметку в классе вашей кастомной вьюхи. Создайте для этого метод и вызывайте его в каждом конструкторе:

```
public LayoutImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init();
}

private void init() {
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.LAYOUT_FILE_NAME_GOES_HERE, this);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Знал что это надо сделать, но не знал как